# Php sessions only work in Google Chrome

Tags: php, session, browser

My php sessions only work in Google Chrome.  Every other browser they don't appear.  Does anyone know why? 
Here is my code for the first page...

```
 <?php 
 // this starts the session 
 session_start(); 

 // this sets variables in the session 
 $_SESSION['color']='red'; 
 $_SESSION['size']='small'; 
 $_SESSION['shape']='round'; 
 print "Done";
 ?>
```

Here is my code for the second page...

```
 <?php 
 // this starts the session 
 session_start(); 

 // echo variable from the session, we set this on our other page 
 echo "Our color value is ".$_SESSION['color']; 
 echo "Our size value is ".$_SESSION['size']; 
 echo "Our shape value is ".$_SESSION['shape']; 
 ?>
```

On the second page it will not display the session variables in any browser other than Chrome.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: make sure the domains match, eg `example.com` and `www.example.com` are different domains.

Comment: Are you sending any content at all to the browser before you're calling session_start()?

Comment: try this to debug:
if(!empty($_SESSION))
   print_r($_SESSION);
else
   echo 'session is empty';

Comment: Make sure you run both page in order on each browsers...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps cookies aren't enabled on your test browsers, or maybe the security level is set too high (for IE).

Try enabling them else make sure they're being set correctly.

Comment: I would have to agree. I just tested it out on my VPS (http://demize95.com/test.php and test2.php) in IE and got this: http://puu.sh/Bcjt